# How to add second line to text on bottom bar for Android?

Tags: android, android-bottomnav, bottombar

I'm trying to have my text go down to a second line so it's not cut off but not sure whether this is possible using the Google MaterialBottomBar?
Something like the image below please.

[image]

But this is what I have:

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_nav" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a style to `BottomNavigation`  in `style.xml`

```
<style name="BottomNavigationStyle">
        <item name="android:lines">2</item>
    </style>
```

And then use above style in your `xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_nav" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a hint to `@chand mohd` answer to have the text centered like that you would like to have.

So, besides `android:lines`, add the `android:gravity` attribute to have a centered text

```
<style name="BottomNavigationStyle">
     <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
     <item name="android:lines">2</item>
</style>
```